# The underlying provider does not support the type 'datetimeoffset'

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to integrate my API, using EF6, with MySQL.
I've installed the package MySql.Data.Entity (version 6.9.7).

Initially, I used Sql Server, so my mapping for date fields used the type DateTimeOffSet. But, when using MySql, I had troubles with that type, so I changed it to DateTime. The migration runs successfully, creates the database in MySql, but in the end of the log shows an error:

```
PM> Update-Database -StartUpProjectName WMoney.WebApi -Verbose
Using StartUp project 'WMoney.WebApi'.
Using NuGet project 'WMoney.Persistence.EntityFramework'.
Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
Target database is: 'wmoney' (DataSource: localhost, Provider: MySql.Data.MySqlClient, Origin: Configuration).
No pending explicit migrations.
System.ArgumentException: The underlying provider does not support the type 'datetimeoffset'.
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderManifest.GetEdmType(TypeUsage storeType)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.BuildColumnModel(EdmProperty property, ModelMetadata modelMetadata, IDictionary`2 annotations)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.BuildAlterColumnOperation(String table, EdmProperty targetProperty, ModelMetadata targetModelMetadata, EdmProperty sourceProperty, ModelMetadata sourceModelMetadata)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.<FindAlteredColumns>b__24a(<>f__AnonymousType2c`2 <>h__TransparentIdentifier242)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.Diff(ModelMetadata source, ModelMetadata target, Lazy`1 modificationCommandTreeGenerator, MigrationSqlGenerator migrationSqlGenerator, String sourceModelVersion, String targetModelVersion)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.Diff(XDocument sourceModel, XDocument targetModel, Lazy`1 modificationCommandTreeGenerator, MigrationSqlGenerator migrationSqlGenerator, String sourceModelVersion, String targetModelVersion)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.IsModelOutOfDate(XDocument model, DbMigration lastMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.UpdateInternal(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClassc.<Update>b__b()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.Run()
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner runner)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Update(String targetMigration, Boolean force)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.UpdateDatabaseCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
The underlying provider does not support the type 'datetimeoffset'.
```

Besides the error, the database is created, and I can run my Api. But, when trying to make a query on DB the same error occurs: "The underlying provider does not support the type 'datetimeoffset'."

I already changed all references to DateTimeOffSet from my code, but the error still happenning.

Does anyone have any idea what can I do to solve this problem?

Thanks

UPDATE:
As requested by DevilSuichiro, I'm adding more informations:

```
MY CONTEXT CLASS:

namespace WMoney.Persistence.EntityFramework
{
    [DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration))]
    public class WMoneyContext : DbContext, IWMoneyContext
    {
        public WMoneyContext()
            : base("WMoneyConnectionString")
            {

            }

        public IUserRepository UserRepository
        { 
            get { return new UserRepository(this); }
        }

        public DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }
        public DbSet<TransactionType> TransactionTypes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            //base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Account>()
                .HasKey(a => a.AccountId)
                .Map(a => a.ToTable("TbAccount", "dbo"));

            modelBuilder.Entity<Account>()
                .HasRequired(a => a.User)
                .WithMany(a => a.Accounts)
                .HasForeignKey(a => a.UserId)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Category>()
                .HasKey(a => a.CategoryId)
                .Map(a => a.ToTable("TbCategory", "dbo"));

            modelBuilder.Entity<Category>()
                .HasRequired(a => a.User)
                .WithMany(a => a.Categories)
                .HasForeignKey(a => a.UserId)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Transaction>()
                .HasKey(a => a.TransactionId)
                .Map(a => a.ToTable("TbTransaction", "dbo"));

            modelBuilder.Entity<Transaction>()
                .HasRequired(a => a.Account)
                .WithMany(a => a.Transactions)
                .HasForeignKey(a => a.AccountId)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Transaction>()
                .HasRequired(a => a.Category)
                .WithMany(a => a.Transactions)
                .HasForeignKey(a => a.CategoryId)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Transaction>()
                .HasRequired(a => a.TransactionType)
                .WithMany(a => a.Transactions)
                .HasForeignKey(a => a.TransactionTypeId)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<TransactionType>()
                .HasKey(a => a.TransactionTypeId)
                .Map(a => a.ToTable("TbTransactionType", "dbo"));

            modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                .HasKey(a => a.UserId)
                .Map(a => a.ToTable("TbUser", "dbo"));
        }



    }
}
```

MY TRANSACTION CLASS (The only with date fields)

```
namespace WMoney.Persistence.Model
{
    public class Transaction
    {
        public int TransactionId { get; set; }

        public int TransactionTypeId { get; set; }

        public DateTime Created { get; set; }

        public DateTime Date { get; set; }

        public int CategoryId { get; set; }

        public int AccountId { get; set; }

        public decimal Value { get; set; }

        [StringLength(200)]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public virtual TransactionType TransactionType { get; set; }

        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

        public virtual Account Account { get; set; }
    }
}
```

MY CLASS WHO CALLS THE DATABASE
The error happens already in the line:
var existentUser = await _userRepository.AsQueryable().GetByEmail(email);

```
namespace WMoney.Core
{
    public class UserCore : IUserCore
    {
        public IUserRepository _userRepository;

        public UserCore(IWMoneyContext wMoneyContext)
        {
            _userRepository = wMoneyContext.UserRepository;
        }

        public async Task<User> CreateUserAsync(string email, string password)
        {
            var existentUser = await _userRepository.AsQueryable().GetByEmail(email);

            if (existentUser != null)
            {
                throw new DuplicateWaitObjectException();
            }

            var user = new User 
            { 
                Email = email,
                Password = password
            };

            await _userRepository.AddAsync(user, true);

            return user;
        }

        public async Task<bool> CheckUserAsync(string email, string password)
        {
            var user = await _userRepository.AsQueryable().GetByEmail(email);

            if (user != null)
            {
                if (user.Password == password)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("There's no user with email '{0}'", email));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: could you show your mapping, your context constructor and one class having this problem?

Comment: I Updated the post with the informations requested by you.